# how to create ps1 file which takes input as json and based on parameters exceute batch file?

Tags: json, powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0

I have this json input

```
[
    {
    Name:"test1.bat",
    Create:"Yes",
    Version:"2"
    },
    {
    Name:"test2.bat",
    Create:"Yes",
    Version:"3"
    },
]
```

test1.bat
//somecode using parameter create version

test2.bat
// somecode using parameter create version

how to create its ps1(powershell script) file?

Comment: Batch files don't have named parameters, how would they need to be used? `test1.bat Yes 2` ?

Comment: yes in that same way

Comment: You can easily find multiple solutions for parsing a JSON file in powershell, as well as invoking a batch file. Downvoting due to zero research effort.

Comment: Sure would like to know the whole premise behind all of this.  You have asked several questions that are very similar over the past few days.  All basically trying to do the same thing.

Comment: I just want to.learn powershell scripting with different aspects and i dont able to find any single good tutorial for this :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Batch-file solution (posted here because this question have the `batch-file` tag) that IMO is simpler than any ps1 solution, but I am sure it run faster than the ps1 solution.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Version="
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:, " %%a in ('findstr ":" input.txt') do (
   set "%%a=%%~b"
   if defined Version (
      ECHO !Name! !Create! !Version!
      set "Version="
   )
)
```

After check that the displayed commands are correct, you must remove the ECHO part in order to *execute* the Batch files. Output example:

```
test1.bat Yes 2
test2.bat Yes 3
```